# Consume RabbitMQ queue as Observable in Grails 3 with RxJava

Tags: grails, rabbitmq, rx-java, observable

Is there a way to consume a RabbitMq in a Grails 3 controller or service as if the Consumer was an Observable?
My actual code is something like that

```
def consumer
rx.stream { Subscriber subscriber ->
     consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
        @Override
        void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope,
                            AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {

            String message = new String(body, "UTF-8")                    
            subscriber.onNext(rx.render(message))

        }
    }
    channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer)
}
```

but I don't really like this kind of implementation and I think adhering to Rx paradigm would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your code to use a pull-based model on the RabbitMQ side instead of a callback-based model? If yes, then you can use `SyncOnSubscribe` to easily fetch messages.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, but I think pull-based model is not really an option since I have to manage near real-time streams pushed from external devices. I don't think I can rely on client polling or infinite loops for pulling messages out of the queue.